# Why do C# automatic properties not support default values like VB 2010?

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-4.0, automatic-properties

Looking at the new VB 2010 features, I stumbled upon support for [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Since I'm working with C#, this seemed quite familiar, but I noticed that VB did add a feature I would love to have in C#: setting an arbitrary default value for the auto-implemented property:

```
Public Class Person

    Property Name As String = "Scott Guthrie"
    Property Age as Integer = 35

End Class
```

I really like the clean usage of auto-properties in C#. This would save us the effort of introducing a backing field and hooking it up to the property every time we simply need a default value, thereby cluttering up the code unnecessarily.

I was wondering why this wasn't introduced in C# as well? What could be the rationale for not doing this? Is a syntax discussion going on, or are there technical limitations to implementing this?

Comment: Why a backing field, no need for that. But I agree that it adds to the clutter.

Comment: PS: you weren't the first to ask, check this for more discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169220/initializing-c-auto-properties

Comment: @Abel: I remember seeing this post. I know it's not possible and how to work around it, but I was curious for the actual rationale why VB does support it and C# not (yet).

Comment: Ok, just found the thread from Microsoft on the subject. It has been a voted request: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/361647/add-initialization-to-automatic-properties-in-c. I updated my answer (again)

Comment: It's been slated for C# 6 anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person() 
    {
         this.Name = "Scott Guthrie";
         this.Age = 35;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

in practice, that comes down to the same and isn't that much extra work, I believe. But perhaps, for once in a long while, VB looks clearer then C#... ;-)

**EDIT (rationale):**
You were asking for the rationale in your last comment under (and in) your original question. Thinking out loud, I think that the principle in C# that initialization code goes to one place and one place only, namely the constructor, is the reason for this decision. Adding another place where you have to look to find initialization code makes debugging harder and the code less clear.

Obviously, an inline initialization value cannot contain other initializations or calculations (at least, very limited). While I agree that it can be more concise in the VB way, I would understand the C# team and Anders Hejlsberg if they said that they consider it a bigger advantage to have one place for initialization.

**EDIT:** [here's what Microsoft says about it](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/361647/add-initialization-to-automatic-properties-in-c). In short, not for C# 4.0, but perhaps C# 5.0? Also:

> *"It is not as easy as it sounds though: 
>   the next thing you want is for the
>   constructor to initialize the backing
>   field, but it can only do that through
>   the setter, which might not be what
>   you want."*

and (just a commenter):

> *"Lack of initialization or constructor
>   control makes the feature practically
>   worthless for properties returning a
>   reference type."*

Comment: James Curran comments on that answer by saying - "DefaultValueAttribute does NOT set the value of a property. All it does is tell Visual Studio what the default value should be, so that in the Property Window, the will be bolded if it is not set to that value. It does not change the value in any way"

Comment: See comment in other thread: "DefaultValueAttribute does NOT set the value of a property. All it does is tell Visual Studio what the default value should be, so that in the Property Window, the will be bolded if it is not set to that value. It does not change the value in any way."

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `DefaultValue` only sets the value for Visual Studio, in the property pane, but does not set the value at execution time.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys, three times ;-). I removed the offending section. You are totally right and it makes sense, considering the way attributes normally work. I should've read it through though.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts and the link to Microsoft's reaction. As I thought, there's simply more to it than just adding extra syntax features. We'll just have to wait for MS to come up with at proper design for this. In the meantime, we'll just have to use the constructor. But I'm still wondering how this works in VB though...

Comment: The layout of http://vbcity.com/blogs/mike-mcintyre/archive/2009/09/07/visual-basic-2010-auto-implemented-properties-a-closer-look.aspx is a bit shaky, but it perhaps answers some of your questions on VB auto properties

Comment: While the code example is basically what Preet's answer is saying, the edits on this answer did provide me some more insight on the rationale behind this, which I was looking for. Therefore I'll accept this as the answer, at least for now ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Why not just default them in the constructor? That's what its for too.

Comment: That's what I usually do, but sometimes it can be helpful to see the defaults at declaration.

Comment: You can have multiple constructors, hence multiple defaults. So while it's a good solution, it's not as clean as supplying a single default value.

Comment: @Jason Williams: If you have multiple constructors, you can use the this-initializer to prevent duplicated code: `public Person(string name) : this() {...}`

Comment: In addition to my other comment: You'll have to remember to implement the constructor and use constructor chaining if you have multiple constructors and don't want to duplicate the initialization code. Seems like a bit of a hassle to me.

Comment: @Preet: This answer provides the preferred way to implement this within the current context, let it be an example for other people!
However it doesn't provide a lot of rationale behind this decision which I was asking for. Abel's answer does a little better at explaining the 'why?'. Thanks though.

Comment: @Abel: Exactly. It would be much easier just to have a default value on the property, wouldn't it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I'm not Microsoft, I would suggest that the perceived benefit was less than the cost to implement, test and support the feature.

Of course, you could just set the default values by declaring a constructor, but I do agree that the VB syntax is a little clearer (especially if you're going to decorate it with metadata such as `<DefaultValue(...)>`)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for the tedious business of converting an auto-property into a property-with-backing-field: My addin, [AtomineerUtils](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) will do that refactoring for you with a single keypress.