# Is it possible to initialize a property at the point of declaration

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Imagine you have a field _items in a class. You can initialize it at the point of declaration:

```
class C
{
  IList<string> _items=new List<string>();
}
```

Now I want to convert this field to an auto generated property, but the initialization is now invalid:

```
class C
{
  public IList<string> Items=new List<string>(); {get; set;} // Invalid
}
```

So, I have to do:

```
class C
{
  public IList<string> Items {get; set;}

  public C
  {
    Items=new List<string>();
  }
}
```

But this is not nearly as convenient as initializing fields at the point of declaration. Is there a better way to do this, without having to (needlessly) back this property with a private (initialized at the point of declaration) field, for example.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you give a C# Auto-Property a default value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-auto-property-a-default-value)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, automatic properties don't allow you to set an initial value.

It's annoying, but such is life. (It's annoying that they can't be readonly, too. But that's a rant for another day.)

EDIT: Both readonly automatically implemented properties and specifying an initial value are slated to be in C# 6.

Comment: It really is indeed. But let's look at it from the good side. We HAVE auto-get set. That alone makes me happy.

Comment: Yes, I would have *loved* being able to type `IList<string> { get; private set; } = new List<string>();` or something similar.

Comment: @Fredrik, that was exactly what I hoped for. Perhaps this would be a good feature to ask for in C# 5?

Comment: @Michael: The C# team is aware that folks including myself would like a bit more control over automatic properties. I'm not personally holding out much hope for seeing it in C# 5, but async/await makes up for it :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yes, indeed it is... along with read-only automatically implemented properties, pretty much how I've requested them for ages :)

Comment: Found a citation: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status Yay!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Indeed. I'm not going to find and edit every old answer that mentions the state of play when I wrote it though...

Comment: @JonSkeet: No, of course not. :-) I just happened to notice.

Answer (score 11):

In c#6 you can write something like this:

```
class C
{
    public IList<string> Items {get; set;} = new List<string>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so - on construction, as you demonstrate, is the next best way so you don't have to use a private backer, and then use constructor-chaining to ensure that the property always gets initialised:

```
public MyClass() { PropA = default_Value; }
public MyClass(params object[] args) : this() { /* other code */ }
```

It would be a nice feature; but then, auto implemented properties are there to simplify property implementation on types; and I can't see how you could add, at the language-level, the default-value feature to an auto-property without the code looking a little, well, odd.

But then, that's why I'm not a language designer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it is not possible to directly initialize an auto property when you declare it. And I agree that this is a pity. I don't know any better way then the constructor either. 
See also [Initializing C# auto-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169220/initializing-c-auto-properties)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't declare the field when you use `{ get; set; }`, you can't specify the initial value.

So you need to declare the field yourself or initialize it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Using a private backing field or setting the value in the constructor are the only ways to give initial values to a Property.