# Instanciate object in auto-generated property

Tags: c#

Is there a way to instanciate an object automatically without instanciate it in the constructor ?

Actually, I have something like :

```
public List<Object> Products { get; set; }
public MyClass()
{
    this.Products = new List<Object>();
}
```

But instead, I would like to instanciate directly my list without specifying in my constructor of my class with something like :

```
public List<Object> Products = new List<Object>(); { get; set; }
```

Is there any trick to do this?

Comment: I don't see this being resolved unless C# introduces non-nullable reference types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jon Skeet Says :

> It's unfortunate that there's no way of doing this right now. You have
>   to set the value in the constructor. (Using constructor chaining can
>   help to avoid duplication.)
>
> Automatically implemented properties are handy right now, but could
>   certainly be nicer. I don't find myself wanting this sort of
>   initialization as often as a read-only automatically implemented
>   property which could only be set in the constructor and would be
>   backed by a read-only field. It's possible that both of these will be
>   fixed in C# 5, which I strongly hope will address immutability
>   concerns. (I don't think either of them are scheduled for C# 4.)

Source : [Initializing C# auto-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169220/initializing-c-sharp-auto-properties)

---

If you need to initialize the `property` `without using the constructor`, you need to use a `backing field`.

Example

```
class Demo
{
    private List<object> myProperty = new List<object>();
    public List<object> MyProperty
    {
        get { return myProperty; }
        set { myProperty = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Who will win, Jon Skeet or Jon Skeet quote?

Comment: Jon Skeet i guess! after all he is a SO legend!

Comment: I hope you at least get an upvote from Jon Skeet!:)

Comment: I just saw it a quote from Jon answer here on the same question, it should be closed as exact duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're asking whether you can give an initial value to an automatically-implemented property. The answer to that question is "no".

You *could* write a manual property though:

```
private List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

public List<Product> Products
{
    get { return products; }
    set { this.products = value; }
}
```

Do you actually need the setter at all? Do you need clients to be able to *replace* the variable value with another list? You may find that you only need a read-only property, in which case you could write:

```
private readonly List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

public IList<Product> Products { get { return products; } }
```

Note that here you can still use a collection initializer, e.g.

```
Foo foo = new Foo
{
    Products = { new Product("foo"), new Product("bar") }
};
```

Comment: Let me be known than I gave you your first +1 over the guy that quoted you answer.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, no not currently with an auto-generated property (though VB.NET auto-properties can do this).  This is something I have often wished for myself.  So you could manually roll your own property, or use a constructor.

Either way you'll have some code you wish you didn't have to write to do this (manual property with no constructor vs. auto-property with constructor).

Interestingly, though, the IL is different between the two options.  When you have a manual property with a backing field using an initializer, it will get executed before the base-class constructor in C#:

```
MyClass..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  newobj      System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Object>..ctor
IL_0006:  stfld       UserQuery+MyClass._products
IL_000B:  ldarg.0     
IL_000C:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0011:  nop         
IL_0012:  ret
```

While using an auto-property with initialization in the constructor will get executed after the base-class constructor in C#:

```
MyClass..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  nop         
IL_0007:  nop         
IL_0008:  ldarg.0     
IL_0009:  newobj      System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Object>..ctor
IL_000E:  call        UserQuery+MyClass.set_Products
IL_0013:  nop         
IL_0014:  nop         
IL_0015:  ret
```

I'm only saying this as a point of curiosity, as writing code that depends on initialization order in .NET can be risky (initialization order in fact differs a bit between VB.NET and C#)

Comment: +1, becuase you know to read IL! I prefer to learn Chinese or any other foreign lang before IL...