# C# Accessor and initialization

Tags: c#, .net

How can we combine c# accessor declaration and initialization

```
List<string> listofcountries= new List<string>();
and 
List<string>listofcountries {get;set;}
```

Is there a way to combine these to statements ?

Comment: You can initialize them in the constructor

Comment: currently I am doing that just curious if there is some other / better way out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value

Answer (score 7):

You can't at the moment. You will be able to in C# 6:

```
List<string> Countries { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

You can even make it a read-only property in C# 6 (hooray!):

```
List<string> Countries { get; } = new List<string>();
```

In C# 5, you can *either* use a non-automatically-implemented property:

```
// Obviously you can make this read/write if you want
private readonly List<string> countries = new List<string>();
public List<string> Countries { get { return countries; } }
```

... or initialize it in the constructor:

```
public List<string> Countries { get; set; }

public Foo()
{
    Countries = new List<string>();
}
```

Comment: i'm looking at an answer by you where you said it's 5 and higher :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169220/initializing-c-sharp-auto-properties

Comment: @eranotzap: Um, no - read it carefully. It says it's *not* available up to and including C# 5, but it's planned to be available in C# 6.

Comment: o'k sorry , my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Only in C# 6.

what i usually like to do is :

```
  private List<string> list;
  public List<string> List
  {
     get
     {
         if(list == null)
         {
            list = new List<string>();
         }

         return list;  
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the constructor, or create a custom getter/setter:

**Constructor**

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        listofcountries = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string> listofcountries { get; set; }
}
```

**Custom Getter/Setter**

```
private List<string> _listofcountries;
public List<string> listofcountries
{
    get
    { 
        if (_listofcountries == null)
        {
            _listofcountries = new List<string>();
        }
        return _listofcountries;
    }
    set { _listofcountries = value; }
}
```

For what it's worth, convention is to have public properties be camel-cased: `ListOfCountries` rather than `listofcountries`. Then the private instance variable for the property would also be camel-cased, but with the first letter lowercase: `listOfCountries` rather than `_listofcountries`.

**UPDATE** Skeet FTW, as usual. Once C# 6 hits, then his answer will be the best way, hands down. In lesser versions, you're stuck with the methods I posted.

Comment: Your custom getter is inappropriate, as if it's null and you use the getter twice, you'll get two different lists - you'd want to assign to `_listofcountries`.

Comment: Right. That's what I get for posting too quickly. Fixed.

Comment: There's also the "write a custom property, but don't bother making it lazy" approach, which means it's just a two-liner... there's no indication that the OP *wants* the allocation to be lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the same statement.
You can do it in the constructor body though