# How do you add initialization to auto-properties

Tags: c#

I'm used to writing classes like this:

```
public class foo {
  private string mBar = "bar";
  public string Bar {
    get { return mBar; }
    set { mBar = value; }
  }
  //... other methods, no constructor ...
}
```

Converting Bar to an auto-property seems convenient and concise, but how can I retain the initialization without adding a constructor and putting the initialization in there?

```
public class foo2theRevengeOfFoo {
  //private string mBar = "bar";
  public string Bar { get; set; }
  //... other methods, no constructor ...
  //behavior has changed.
}
```

You could see that adding a constructor isn't inline with the effort savings I'm supposed to be getting from auto-properties.

Comment: STOP ANSWERING. LOOK HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169220/initializing-c-sharp-auto-properties congrats for making 100% duplicate

Answer (score 1):

This [MS Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx) explains:

> Auto-property initializers are now enabled, and are similar to initializers on fields

```
public class Customer 
{ 
    public string First { get; set; } = "Jane"; 
    public string Last { get; set; } = "Doe"; 
}
```