# Making a property getter and setter equal something (auto-property initializer)

Tags: c#, properties

What's the difference between:

```
public List<MyType> Something{ get; set; } = new List<MyType>();
```

and

```
public List<MyType> Something{ 
    get{
        return new List<MyType>();
    }
    //set...
}
```

**Context:**
I'm unsure of the behaviour I'm seeing in my code. A service is there on constructor, but `null` on a future method call in the what I assume is the same instance of the class.

Comment: What reason for the down vote :) ? Straight to the point, Only included what was needed for the question, searched for whatever i could find regarding it but do not know the words to search correctly for it. Not sure what else i could have done here to make the question better? Plus i got the answer within seconds.

Comment: Could be because the code does not compile. `'Something.set' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial`

Comment: Thanks @fredrik - I've updated the Q for future peeps.

Comment: You could have easily debugged this behavior by adding a break point, a that point you *should* have noticed the `return new List<MyType>();` being called every time you accessed the getter. Also you should have include *why* you were asking the question, I presume because maybe you were not seeing the content of the list being persisted.

Comment: My issue was related to the instantiation of a service that was there once, but not there a second time. So was confused by the difference/behaviour. That's why i came here. Thanks for your input though @Igor

Comment: "but null on a future method call in the what i assume is the same instance of the class." that is indeed strange behaviour. something else inside the class that sets the service to `null` inbetween?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first line:

```
public List<MyType> Something{ get; set; } = new List<MyType>();
```

will be called once when the object (that has this property) is instantiated. It is a one time creation of an instance of `Something`.

The second example is an explicit implementation of the getter. Every time you access the getter of `Something` it will return a new and empty list.

EDIT:

The first line is called an [auto-property initializer](http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2015/06/30/whatrsquos-new-in-c-6.0-auto-property-initializers.aspx) for a detailed answer have a look at [a post by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/169872/5174469). This feature exists since C# 6.0

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense considering the behaviour i'm seeing :D

Comment: Thanks for the addition!

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 did the answer help you? would you care to accept ?=! or are you waiting for further answers to arrive ? Cheers mate