# Initializing a List Property

Tags: c#, list, properties

I am writing a program for an SSIS process, and part of what it does is read rows from a data flow and pack them into a List of String Arrays `List<string[]>`. My main class contains the Updated List, but I have an EmailBuilder Class which needs to access the Updated List field to write an HTML E-Mail message. Right now, my code looks like this:

Fields

```
public static List<string[]> Updated = new List<string[]>();
```

ProcessInputRow

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    if (Row.Missing_IsNull)
    {
        Updated.Add(new string[] { Row.Name, Row.PreviousOutstanding.ToString(), Row.PreviousDate.ToString(), Row.CurrentOutstanding.ToString(), Row.CurrentDate.ToString()});
    }
    else
    {
        Missing.Add(Row.Missing);
    }
}
```

Of course, the problem here is that my field is *public*, which is a no-no. I tried using the built-in properties:

```
public static List<string[]> Updated { get; private set; }
```

But this returns a Null Exception, I assume because at that point I haven't actually created the list. So, how could I implement this code safely? I can't seem to manipulate it such that I can access the field from outside the class without making it a public field. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `public static List<string[]> UpdatedSecurities { get; } = new List<string[]>();`, or stay with `{ get; private set; }` and initialize it in the constructor. When you say "the built-in properties", what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean using the auto-generated code that's made with { get; } instead of writing out { get { return updated } set { updated = value } }. My bad on naming that UpdatedSecurities, I meant to call it Updated for simplicity. Could you explain what you mean when you say initialize in the constructor? I'm not familiar.

Comment: Ok. Either way, try my suggestions. I wouldn't, by the way, have an absolute existential crisis about making a field public. A read/write public property vs a public field, it's much of a muchness (unless you're in WPF with databinding, but I think you're not).

Comment: Constructor: I should have said "static constructor". `Updated` is a member of a class. You don't say what its name is, so I'll call it Brian: `public class Brian { static Brian() { Updated = new List<string[]>(); } public static List<string[]> Updated { get; private set; } /* much other stuff */ }`. That `static Brian()` method is a static constructor, called the first time anything touches your class. It's for initializing static members such as `Updated`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing C# auto-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169220/initializing-c-sharp-auto-properties)

Comment: I'm not really messing with databinding in the script at all (SSIS is handling that). It's good to hear that it isn't as big a deal as i thought it was overall, and it's also great to understand the right way to do it if I had to. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

It's better to hide your fields, even if it's not essential. You can initialize the auto properties like this if you are using C# 6 or later.

```
public static List<string[]> Updated { get; private set; } = new List<string[]>();
public static List<TheOtherType> Missing { get; private set; } = new List<TheOtherType>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to keep the field private but make changes to it from outside the class. Is it ok to use a public method that does this? Or property?

Like

```
MainClass
{
  ...
  otherClass.AddToPrivateList("content")
}
```

Comment: Answers usually don't ask a lot of questions.